# Show TextBox on every TabPage

Tags: c#, textbox, tabcontrol, tabpage

I attached a `TextBox` to the first `TabPage` of a `TabControl`. I would like to display the same `TextBox` object on every `TabPage`. I tried to add the control to the `tabControl` Collection but unfortunately it's not working.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

Comment: Change the text boxes tab on changing of the tab.. so it moves..

Comment: Just change the control's Parent property in the SelectedIndexedChanged event.  You surely can't completely ignore the need to do something with its Location and TabIndex properties however.  So maybe this is one shortcut too many.

Answer (score 1):

Button b;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        b = new Button() { Text = "Prueba" };
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddButtonToTabControl();
    }

    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddButtonToTabControl();
    }

    public void AddButtonToTabControl()
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed two methods. It's working now!

```
tabControl1.Selecting += new TabControlCancelEventHandler(tabControl1_Selecting);


    void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
    {

        tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls.Add(textBox);
    }
```